# htaccess ModRewrite to Root Directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I don't know a huge amount about htacess and modrewrite, so I find myself in yet another predicament approaching this new zone for myself.

I will seperate my Inquiries over 2 different questions to allow answers to be on-topic and better targetted to users searching for solutions to their own questions.

Let me first start with one that should be easy but I have probably overlooked;

```
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^domain.com.au [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com.au/$1 [R=301,NC]
```

As you can see I want www. in the URL, I also force https using a php script but thought it better to simply use this to handle both so that the user doesnt have to wait for 2 forwards to occur.

The above code seems to work fine, however it takes you to the root of the domain.

```
http://domain.com/index.php?page=hello
http://domain.com/dir/index.php?page=hello
http://domain.com/dir17/sub/index.php?page=hello
```

All 3 of the above URLS will redirect to https://www.domain.com/index.php?page=hello

Obviously It is to do with the directory depth of the modrewrite but I dont know how to ensure that it locally applies it to each directory instead of simply directing back to the root.

I appreciate your help as always, amazing group of people on this website :)

Comment: Hmm, what you are showing here indicates that you might have some other rewrite rules interfering with this.  the rule you provided should work exactly as you expect it to otherwise. Please look around for other .htaccess files in your directories, and make sure the rule you posted as above is in the _root_ directory's .htaccess.

Comment: I am currently using it in a hidden subdirectory for testing purposes as this section of the site is yet to go live, it is in the root of THAT directory but not in the site root. Does that make a difference in this scenarior with that rule?

Comment: Furthermore to your answer, I placed said rule in the root directory and it just causes weird 401 errors and seems like its just messing with me now :(

Comment: What do you want to do? redirect to **same URI** but on https and specific hostname? or does original hostname come into play somehow?

Comment: I want www. to always be apart of the URL and I want https forced on the user at all times, no matter the section of the website or directory level (Different staff use different systems, currently each runs its own PHP script to force an HTTPS connection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little late but realised that it never had an answer posted. I did however resolve it after a good amount of research;

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

I certainly hope this helps someone else.